# Type $F_n$ and quasi-isometry with highly connected space

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Recall that a group is of *type $F_n$* if it has a classifying space with finite $n$-skeleton. For example type $F_1$ means finitely generated, and type $F_2$ means finitely presented.

Question: For a finitely generated group $G$, is $G$ being of type $F_n$ equivalent to $G$ being quasi-isometric to an $(n-1)$-connected geodesic metric space?

The forward direction is true: Suppose $G$ is of type $F_n$, let $X$ be a classifying space for $G$ with finite $n$-skeleton, and let $Y$ be the $n$-skeleton of the universal cover of $X$. Now $Y$ is a connected locally finite (hence metrizable, and following some tricks, WLOG geodesic) CW-complex on which $G$ acts geometrically, so Svarc-Milnor says $G$ is quasi-isometric to $Y$. Also, $Y$ is $(n-1)$-connected, being the $n$-skeleton of a contractible complex.

The backward direction is less clear to me: If $G$ is quasi-isometric to an $(n-1)$-connected geodesic metric space, must it be of type $F_n$? Note that Prop 6.1 of [https://www.normalesup.org/~cornulier/shang.pdf](https://www.normalesup.org/%7Ecornulier/shang.pdf) says that this is true for $n=2$ (i.e., if $G$ is QI to a simply connected geodesic metric space then it is finitely presented). But I can't find anything in the literature for $n>2$.

If it is true, then this would be a nice "geometric group theory"-style definition of type $F_n$, namely being quasi-isometric to an $(n-1)$-connected geodesic metric space. But I can't tell if it's actually true.

Comment: The answer is no for $n=2$, in the absence of the geodesic assumption, there are "stupid" counterexamples (just consider a covering tree in the Cayley graph: every f.g. is QI to a metric space that is homeomorphic to a tree, hence contractible). So you probably want to add the geodesic assumption.

Comment: Did you check the book by Ross Geoghegan?

Comment: @YCor Aha, good point. I'll add "geodesic". I think it can be safely added without nullifying the forward direction.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I know Ross gives a proof that $F_n$ is a QI-invariant, but I don't think he does anything that doesn't begin with some assumption of some group or other being type $F_n$ already.

Comment: I don't know if this remark might interest you, but being of type $F_n$ is equivalent to being coarsely $n$-connected, i.e. Rips complexes are eventually connected + for every $r$ there exists $R \geq r$ such that the obvious map between the Rips complexes $\mathrm{Rips}_r(X) \to \mathrm{Rips}_R(X)$ is trivial on each $\pi_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. Details can be found in Drutu and Kapovich's book.

Comment: @AGenevois Yup, that's a nice result (or, you mean coarsely $(n-1)$-connected), and it's actually pretty much immediate from Brown's Criterion - the cool thing Drutu and Kapovich additionally do is show that when $n=2$ and $r$ is large you can get away with $R=r$.

Comment: @AGenevois And maybe I should have said in the original question (but it was getting bulky already), thanks this Rips filtration thing, in order to prove the desired result, it's enough to show that if $X$ is an $(n-1)$-connected geodesic metric space then $X$ is also coarsely $(n-1)$-connected. This seems obviously true linguistically, but actually, Rips complexes of geodesic metric spaces are pretty weird, and it's not clear to me.

Comment: A philosophical remark: there are two flavors of GGT: one about coarsely geodesic spaces (f.g. groups) up to QI and one about general spaces up to coarse equivalence. I think finiteness properties belong to the second flavor because (a) they are coarse invariants and (b) being finitely generated is one of the properties so you don't want to assume it up front. So I think being coarsely (n-1)-connected *is* the GGT-style definition.

Comment: Lemma 2.24 of  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.01496.pdf makes a connection between actual topology and coarse topology. But it assumes that (non-empty intersections of) large balls are contractible (in an ambient space) so that the full topology of the union is visible in the nerve. But a space that is not $n$-connected, will have balls that are not $n$-connected.